# Examine convergence of $\int_0^1 \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$

Tags: integration

Examine convergence of $$\int_0^1 \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$$

Let's do comparison test:
$$ -1 \le  \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \le 1 \\
\underbrace{\int_0^1 -1}_{\mbox{converges to -1-0 = -1}} \le \int_0^1 \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \le \underbrace{\int_0^1 1}_{\mbox{converges to 1-0 = 1}} $$

so integral converges. Is that true?

Comment: You have to be a little careful because $0\not\leq\cos(1/\sqrt{x})$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. But you *can* show that the integral in absolute value is bounded above by $1$ (using the triangle inequality and the inequality you've stated). Thus the integral converges.

Comment: @Clayton $\underbrace{\int_0^1 -1}_{\mbox{converges to -1-0 = -1}} \le \int_0^1 \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \le \underbrace{\int_0^1 1}_{\mbox{converges to 1-0 = 1}} $ so my integral converges. Is that good explanation?

Comment: Yes, the integral does converge.